# plugin iOS augmented reality in PhoneGap

Tags: ios, cordova, plugins

i have a problem with my plugin iOS in PhoneGap. i red this tutorial ( http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/extending-phonegap-with-native-plugins-for-ios.html ) .after that , i created my plugin based on this project (https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/ChildBrowser ) for the plugin and this one ( https://github.com/zac/iphonearkit/ ) for the augmented reality native code .

the code works but i don't have a result for augmented reality displayed. how can i have the result of the running code ?

Comment: without the code its little hard to judge it, code will help. But anyways worst case, check whether your success/error callbacks are registered/invoked properly.